# Couldn't read from the cursor android

Tags: java, android, cursor, setbackground

I faced a problem when working on my project and i don't know what this means.

This is the log :

```
07-15 13:15:14.839      851-879/android.process.acore I/ContactLocale﹕ AddressBook Labels [en-US]: [, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Α, Β, Γ, Δ, Ε, Ζ, Η, Θ, Ι, Κ, Λ, Μ, Ν, Ξ, Ο, Π, Ρ, Σ, Τ, Υ, Φ, Χ, Ψ, Ω, , А, Б, В, Г, Д, Ђ, Е, Є, Ж, З, И, І, Ї, Й, Ј, К, Л, Љ, М, Н, Њ, О, П, Р, С, Т, Ћ, У, Ф, Х, Ц, Ч, Џ, Ш, Щ, Ю, Я, , א, ב, ג, ד, ה, ו, ז, ח, ט, י, כ, ל, מ, נ, ס, ע, פ, צ, ק, ר, ש, ת, , ا, ب, ت, ث, ج, ح, خ, د, ذ, ر, ز, س, ش, ص, ض, ط, ظ, ع, غ, ف, ق, ك, ل, م, ن, ه, و, ي, , ก, ข, ฃ, ค, ฅ, ฆ, ง, จ, ฉ, ช, ซ, ฌ, ญ, ฎ, ฏ, ฐ, ฑ, ฒ, ณ, ด, ต, ถ, ท, ธ, น, บ, ป, ผ, ฝ, พ, ฟ, ภ, ม, ย, ร, ฤ, ล, ฦ, ว, ศ, ษ, ส, ห, ฬ, อ, ฮ, , ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅎ, , あ, か, さ, た, な, は, ま, や, ら, わ, #, ]
07-15 13:15:15.116      851-863/android.process.acore I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6846(329KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 43% free, 628KB/1117KB, paused 1.458ms total 130.305ms
07-15 14:20:18.599      851-920/android.process.acore V/BackupServiceBinder﹕ doBackup() invoked
07-15 14:20:18.663      851-920/android.process.acore E/DictionaryBackupAgent﹕ Couldn't read from the cursor
```

All i want is to set the background of my relative layout, before that the app was working.

I am doing this way :

```
RelativeLayout r;
Bitmap background;
r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLay_main);
background = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(this.getResources(), getResourceID("background", "drawable", this), 100, 100);
r.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), background));
```

I know `setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated and i use also `setBackground`.
The method `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` is from `developer.android` site.

What means that crash? And how to get rid of it?

What is very strange, is that it gives me this error only on some images, not all (random, but still) ...

Thank you

Comment: That error might not be related to your problem. Perhaps post a longer log snip and code.

Comment: thats all the log i am getting

Comment: Have you enabled [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder.html) in your app?  I'm pretty confident the log messages you posted are not caused by the code you posted.  You say your app crashed.  Did you actually get an exception or just log messages you posted?

Comment: no, i haven't changed anything on `StrictMode` , just the log mesages...